# Dijkstra variation in Neo4j - find all paths

Tags: java, algorithm, neo4j, dijkstra

I am using Neo4J to understand the popularity of holiday destinations, in terms of where someone has visited and what they are likely to next be interested in based on people with similar travel schemes to them.

I have a Neo4 Database, where I have nodes, representing the location and relationships representing where they have come from then gone to.

For example, I have one "Venice" -> "Rome" with a count 300.

Now I want to understand the paths created, to predict a path of lets say 10 locations, that are likely for people to go to: "venice" -> "rome" -> "vienna" -> "barcelona" -> "madrid" -> ...

Aims of this project:

- I want to understand all paths between any two nodes (all pairs of nodes)
- Restrict the paths to a maximum of length 10, but should also get paths if found, length 4 etc.
- Use Dijiktra's - but a version which focuses on choosing the maximum count - should I invert the count?

I have been looking into iteration through all nodes, and then finding the paths with another node. This would involve a nested for loop and some variation on Dijkstra .

There has been discussion on how to get all nodes [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/57kEwRQ-KSE)

My questions are:

- Whether this approach is suitable?
- How to create your own path finding algorithm - or vary the existing algorithms? - Dijkstra
- Is there a more efficient way to do all of this, rather than iteration through nodes?

Answer (score 2):

I put something like this up at http://gist.neo4j.org/?9363884, which shows how to hold meta information about paths in nodes, and denote differente paths with relationship types. This will probably not do for the All Paths query you want to do, but might give you some modeling hints.

For the all-paths, I would write my own algo in Java and use it either as a Server Plugin or directly from Java code, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html